# javafx 2 webview custom url handler, don't work relative url

Tags: java, webview, javafx-8

I have simple app with code:

```
webView.getEngine().load("classpath:data/index.html");
```

Custom URLStreamHandler:

```
public class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {
    private final ClassLoader classLoader;

    public Handler() {
        this.classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    }

    public Handler(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        this.classLoader = classLoader;
    }

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
        URL resourceUrl = classLoader.getResource(u.getPath());
        if(resourceUrl == null)
            throw new IOException("Resource not found: " + u);

        return resourceUrl.openConnection();
    }
}
```

installed by:

```
URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(protocol -> {
    if(protocol.equals("classpath")) {
        return new Handler();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

It load data/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello, World!!!</div>
<img src="download.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

but in result image doesn't appears.

What to do to allow WebView resolve relative link like "download.jpg"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thin I found the solution:

in `Handler.openConnection(URL u)` we have to add

```
String path = getURL().getPath().startsWith("/") ? getURL().getPath().substring(1) : getURL().getPath();
URL resourceUrl = classLoader.getResource(path);
```

instead of

```
URL resourceUrl = classLoader.getResource(u.getPath());
```

and to standartize URL, instead

```
webView.getEngine().load("classpath:data/index.html");
```

use

```
webView.getEngine().load("classpath:///data/index.html");
```

Comment: how did you "install" the custom handler?