# JavaFX detecting 404 responses from WebEngine

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

Using JavaFx WebEngine, how can I detect if there is a 404 page not found error. I have searched but not able to find anything. Any ideas? or Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried listening to the worker status? Maybe it shows a State.FAILED status?

Comment: Nope it does not. It shows Success. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you would have to add your own URL handler (like in this post [javafx 2 webview custom url handler, don't work relative url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709777/javafx-2-webview-custom-url-handler-dont-work-relative-url)) and retrieve/detect 404 messages and conditions yourself.

This article ([How to check if a URL exists or returns 404 with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378199/how-to-check-if-a-url-exists-or-returns-404-with-java)) shows you how to detect a 404 condition.

In the handler you have 2 choices, either create a `HEAD` request for a URL (and subsequently ignore `HEAD` requests so you don't get yourself into an infinite loop) or masquerade the returned URLConnection after checking for a 404.

```
@Override
protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
    // 1. Use Apache HTTPClient or something else to grab the url
    // 2. Read the resultCode and report if it's a 404
    // 3. Return an object that subclasses URLConnection
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check and update here.

Comment: What a horrible solution!  Changing a write-once JVM-global property that's invasive enough to screw up the entire classloading mechanism... just to be able to read a status code.